# Change vertical Distance in my Cover Letter - ModernCv

Tags: spacing, moderncv, vertical

I am currently writing an application with moderncv that is almost finished but I have small problem that I cant fix on my own.

I my example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{red} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Max} 
\familyname{Mustermann} 

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Musterstadt}{Musterland}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\clearpage

\recipient{HR}{Muster Firma} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Mr.} 
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\enclosure[Anlagen]{}

\makelettertitle

\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3] 



\end{document}
```

you can cleary see that vertical distance between the salutation (Dear Mr) and the first part of the text is twice as big as the distance between the two parts of the text.

What do i need to change/add so that the distance between the salutation and the text is the same?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) nice mwe, (3) might be a good idea to add an image of what you get on your end. Then the _you can cleary see_ makes a bit more sense

Answer (score 1):

Well, a dirty hack is to use command `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` to get rid of one blank line after the opening of the letter.  Just try it like this:

```
\vspace{-\baselineskip} % <=============================================
\lipsum[2]
```

Please see the following complete TeX code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{red} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Max} 
\familyname{Mustermann} 

\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Musterstadt}{Musterland}

\makeatletter

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\clearpage

\recipient{HR}{Muster Firma} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Mr.} 
\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\enclosure[Anlagen]{}

\makelettertitle
\vspace{-\baselineskip} % <=============================================
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[3] 



\end{document}
```

and its resulting cover letter:

[image: resulting cover letter]

The first biger space for the opening is okay as it is, the second space after the opening is now smaller as wished ...